# Changing text line spacing

Tags: itext

I'm creating a PDF document consisting of text only, where all the text is the same point size and font family but each character could potentially be a different color.  Everything seems to work fine using the code snippet below, but the default space between the lines is slightly greater than I consider ideal.  Is there a way to control this? (FYI, type "ColoredText" in the code below merely contains a string and its color.  Also, the reason I am treating the newline character separately is that for some reason it doesn't cause a newline if it's in a Chunk.)

Thanks,
Ray

```
List<byte[]> pdfFilesAsBytes = new List<byte[]>();
iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memStream);
document.SetPageSize(isLandscape ? iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER.Rotate() : iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER);
document.Open();
foreach (ColoredText coloredText in coloredTextList)
{
    Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, pointSize, Font.NORMAL, coloredText.Color);
    if (coloredText.Text == "\n")
       document.Add(new Paragraph("", font));
    else
        document.Add(new Chunk(coloredText.Text, font));
}
document.Close();
pdfFilesAsBytes.Add(memStream.ToArray());
```

Comment: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Paragraph.html setSpacingAfter()

Answer (score 53, accepted):

According to the PDF specification, the distance between the baseline of two lines is called the *leading*. In iText, the default leading is 1.5 times the size of the font. For instance: the default font size is 12 pt, hence the default leading is 18.

You can change the leading of a `Paragraph` by using one of the other constructors. See for instance: [public Paragraph(float leading, String string, Font font)](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/Paragraph.html#Paragraph-float-java.lang.String-com.itextpdf.text.Font-)

You can also change the leading using one of the methods that sets the leading:

```
paragraph.SetLeading(fixed, multiplied);
```

The first parameter is the fixed leading: if you want a leading of 15 no matter which font size is used, you can choose fixed = 15 and multiplied = 0.

The second parameter is a factor: for instance if you want the leading to be twice the font size, you can choose fixed = 0 and multiplied = 2. In this case, the leading for a paragraph with font size 12 will be 24, for a font size 10, it will be 20, and son on.

You can also combine fixed and multiplied leading.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I thought that this wouldn't apply to Chunks but it was just my misunderstanding of how all this fits together.  It worked perfectly. Ray

Comment: Yes, I can see what caused the confusion: a `Chunk` doesn't have a leading, but when added to a document, the `Chunk` is always added in the context of a `Phrase` or `Paragraph` (explicitly or implicitly) in which case it uses the leading of that object.

Comment: So how can one control the spacing before the Paragraph independently of the spacing between lines in the paragraph?  If I try setting the multiplier spacing to 1 (i.e. no spacing between lines), that also wipes out the space before the paragraph, when inserted into the cell.

Comment: Did you look at the `setSpacingBefore()` method?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, the default leading in iText 7 is now 1.35 (multiplied), see https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/8ae1279ff81ebd3b3cd7c11468f53bff698b83c0/layout/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/layout/element/Paragraph.java#L178

Answer (score 4):

```
    private static Paragraph addSpace(int size = 1)
    {

        Font LineBreak = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", size);      
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("\n\n", LineBreak);
        return paragraph;

    }
```